# When to answer, when to comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

When looking at questions on StackOverflow these days I can't help but notice that most questions don't get a "proper" answer anymore. Instead, they are lots of comments to the question which try to answer it. I even had it that when I wrote a "proper" answer I was getting downvotes because I could have written a comment. Now I don't really mind the downvotes, as everyone can vote as he or she pleases, however it got me thinking if I'm doing things the wrong way.

As far as I understand the system, comments are for asking clarification questions and answers are where you put your answer in. The whole reputation system works around this assumption. Also from a usability point of view burying the answer in a thread of comments which is only shown after some clicking doesn't seem right either.

So are there some guidelines on when to put answers into comments instead of doing a "proper" answer that I just missed or did I just happen to see a pattern where no pattern exists and the majority of questions is still getting "proper" answers?

Comment: First: StackOverflow Meta. Second: Show specific examples, please. Anyway, it is quite simple, answer if you actually have an answer or write a comment for anything else like questions for clarification or wishy-washy stuff like "have you tried xyz?". If you then are able to write a proper answer from your initial comment (for example due to feedback from OP), then do so.

Answer (score 5):

You are right: answers are for answers, comments are for clarification.

In the SE network, and especially on SO, I see the same tendency on low-quality questions. Users are reluctant to post an answer, either because they think the author should have made more effort, or because they know they can be downvoted for answering low-quality questions (you can debate that, but it happens, more often though those posts are heavily upvoted). Instead they give a 'helpful comment', usually a single line of code.

So when does a 'helpful comment' become answer? It mostly depends on the level of usefulness. I can quickly write a comment "Use a dictionary", but that is not an answer. An answer should explain what the solution is and how to achieve that. On SO that will usually mean some working code.

Comment: There is a third possible reason for a comment, rather then an answer: they know that the question is off-topic and about to be deleted and won't hinder that deletion process, but still help OP.

Comment: Yes, that is true. However, that seems totally against the 'bad questions will be closed, you don't get an answer' rule. I hoped more users would avoid being 'helpful' to such authors.